# How to insert Lat and Lng to point type column in mysql with laravel?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, laravel, spatial

this is my code

```
$map_point->map_id = $id;
$map_point->point = GeomFromText('POINT('.$lat .' '.$lng.')');
$map_point->save();
```

it gives me

```
Call to undefined function GeomFromText()
```

so what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

`GeomFromText` is actually a MySQL function that is executed in SQL. If you need to use it you will have to use `DB::raw("GeomFromText('POINT('.$lat .' '.$lng.')')")`

I have never tried using `DB::raw()` on a model yet, but, in theory it could work. But, this may mean you will need to use a Query builder query to do this instead of Eloquent.

Also, be VERY CAREFUL about including variables directly when using `DB::raw` or query builder. These are possible injection points.